# nginx loadbalancer conf file parse python

Tags: python, file, nginx, split, config

I have a nginx conf file like this:

```
upstream server1.stack.com {
   zone server1.stack.com 2048k;
   #least_time header;
   least_conn;
   keepalive 256;
   server 10.10.12.141:3311 max_fails=0 slow_start=10s;
   server 10.10.12.141:33311 max_fails=0 slow_start=10s;
}
server {
   listen 10.11.128.194:80 backlog=102400 reuseport;
   server_name server1.stack.com;
   status_zone server1.stack.com;
   location / {
       proxy_pass http://server1.stack.com;
       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Connection "";
       #health_check;
   }
   location @hc {
       proxy_pass http://server1.stack.com;
       proxy_set_header Host server1.stack.com;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Connection "";
       health_check uri=/status interval=3 fails=2 passes=2;
       error_log /var/log/nginx/error_hc.log info;
   }
}
```

And I want to parse this file like this:

```
server1.stack.com = {'zone':['server1.stack.com','2048k',';'],'#least_time':['header',';'],'least_conn':[';']'live':['256',';'],'server':['10.10.12.141:3311','max_fails=0','slow_start=10s',';']}...
```

Key: zone
Value: server1.stack.com, 2048, ;

or if you have a different suggestion I will gladly listen.

I want to send all config to web page form inputs But I did not split the config.

Comment: Have you looked at this?  https://github.com/nginxinc/crossplane

Comment: @JasonBaumgartner thanks for answering but this is for nginx conf file. I tried but not work. My file is nginx loadbalancer conf file